# solidity compiler hashing function

Tags: solidity, remix, truffle-contract, compiler, hash-algorithm

What hashing function or encoding scheme does solidity default compiler use  to encode or hash the data of smart contracts in remix ide?

Comment: Do you mean the data you send to the contract through transactions, or the data stored by the contract on the blockchain?

Comment: I mean when compiling the code on remix solidity default compiler use which hashing function?

Comment: In Ethereum the principal hashing algorithm is keccak. The compiler should only uses hashing for the [contract metadata](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/metadata.html#contract-metadata).